# Extracting Data by "html_nodes" with two conditions

Tags: html, r, nodes

I'm trying to extract a price list from a particular site

```
price <- paste0("price", 1:24)
dfprice <- as.data.frame(price)
for (i in datalist){
  PanInfos <- html_nodes(i, css = '.info')
```

and when it's a normal price, it's normally extracted in the following way.

```
  PRICE <- 
    PanInfos %>% 
    html_nodes('.price') %>% 
    html_text()

  length(PRICE) <- nrow(dfprice)      
  PRICE <- as.data.frame(PRICE)
  dfprice <- cbind(dfprice, PRICE
}
```

In general,HTML is consisted like below,

```
<span class = "price-button">
   <span itemprop = "price" class = "price">
```

But when it sale, they give two price text like below

```
<span class ="now">
   <span class = "price">
      <span itemprop="price" class="price">

<span class = "reduction">
   <span class = "price">
      <span itemprop = "price" class="price">
```

So, when I extract data by html_nodes('.price'), I extract more price information then I need. Like, I have 24 list of Products name, but 25 price information because of that.

To sum up, I'd like to extract the prices at a normal price and discount prices with different conditions. I really need your help.

Comment: You could try specifying the level above with something like:  `%>%html_nodes('span.now .price')`

Comment: But If I do just : %>%html_nodes('span.now .price'), Only extract sale price only... Normal Price's span class = "price-button" . I need "Price-button" Or "Now" html_nodes.